# Is there any way to perform validation with xsd before calling a web service method

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl, xsd-validation

I have a wcf webservice which has several methods. I also have several xsd schemas that i want to use to validate created xmls. What i am curious about is there any way to perform validation before making a web service call ? If it is valid make the request, if not stop and return the xsd validation message.

For instance,

I have a method that makes member registration.  Lets say It has name and age parameters. I want to check that user doesn't enter string to the age parameter before making the ws call. Also how to import these xsd files to the client machine ? Is there any way to generate them on client by wsdl or some other way ?

Answer (score 0):

If it is a case of type or format input this should probably be done on the client with the UI layer to save any processing.

If you have a web based client using MVC you can easily add attributes to the model to validate the input, if you have a SPA utilizing a javascript framework like angularJS, this could all be done on the client side before the user can even submit the data.

Comment: If the case is that the clients are directly invoking the ws method before validating the method' parameters that is sent. I mean the client will get a message by xsd, before the ws method goes to server. If xsd validates the xml which is generated by  the method then go to the server and take response. I want to decrease the round-trip